# System Overview Diagram for Wordpress website?

Tags: wordpress, system

I am trying to get my head around the system for a website using a Wordpress theme. I'm particularly confused at where Wordpress fits in, is it in the database, server or is it a standalone?? Here is the diagram I have made so far:[image] Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WordPress is a content management system (CMS). It is built with php code, runs on a HTTP server, connects to a database and renders html/css/javascript to the client.

WordPress usually runs on Apache HTTP server, and connects to a mysql database though it can be configured to run on other HTTP servers and connect to other database servers (like SqlServer).

A WordPress theme is used to define rules of how to render WordPress content (entered through the WordPress admin interface) fetched from the database to the client (read browser) as HTML/CSS/JavaScript/Images. A WordPress theme follows WordPress template hierarchy for rendering different pages (You can learn more about that here: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/)

You can learn more about WordPress site architecture here:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Site_Architecture_1.5

Comment: Thaks for your reply, would you say the updated image is more like the system then going from your answer??

Comment: I would say that wordpress is where you see php in this image. http://mainwpex.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/HTML-Request.gif
A wordpress theme is part of WordPress cms.

Comment: I've updated the image again trying to incorporate that link, replacing Wordpress with the php in the image. Am I on the right track would you say?

Comment: I wouldn't say so. WordPress Theme is part of WordPress... it is not an external entity to WordPress. Also, WordPress is served by the Server... it is not communicating with the Server.

Comment: That was what I was trying to portray by using the boxes rather than arrows to section the relationships of the elements. Perhaps the latest update is clearer? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Better. The arrow to database should be bidirectional and also both request to server and response from server goes through the isp.

Comment: Think I have it now. Image is updated as you suggested. Thank you for your help!!

Comment: That image link seems to be broken. @MirzaP Any chance to update its link?